# Verify signature in C++ using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl

I want to verify a signature in C++ , which is a random I have signed in Java.

Here is the Java code I used for signing it:

```
public byte[] sign(byte[] random, PrivateKey privateKey){
    byte[] signedRandom = null;

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(random);
    signedRandom = signature.sign();

    return signedRandom;
}
```

Now i want to verify the signature in C++, I need C++ code equals the following Java code:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(originalRandom);
signature.verify(signedRandom);
```

What I have tried so far:

```
  int verifySignedRandom(unsigned char *signedRandom, unsigned char * originalRandom){
        EVP_MD_CTX c;

        EVP_MD_CTX_init(&c);
        EVP_VerifyInit(&c, EVP_sha256());
        EVP_VerifyUpdate(&c, originalRandom, (unsigned int)sizeof(originalRandom));
        return EVP_VerifyFinal(&c, signedRandom, (unsigned int)strlen((char *)signedRandom), savedPublicKey);
        //savedPublicKey was set somewhere else...
    }
```

This method returns 0, but I´m sure the random was signed with the right key and the method needs to return 1...I think there is something wrong with my C++ code for verifying. Maybe one of you know how to do it right.

--Solution--

```
int verifySignedRandom(unsigned char *signedRandom, int signedRandomSize, unsigned char * originalRandom, int originalSize){
    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    const EVP_MD *md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");

    if(!md){
        printf("Error creating md");
    }

    EVP_VerifyInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL);
    EVP_VerifyUpdate(ctx, originalRandom, originalSize);
    return EVP_VerifyFinal(ctx, signedRandom, signedRandomSize, savedUserPkey);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    EVP_VerifyUpdate(&c, originalRandom, (unsigned int)sizeof(originalRandom));
```

This line looks buggy. `sizeof(originalRandom)` is always `sizeof(unsigned char*)` which is usually either 4 or 8. You should pass the correct length instead.

Java arrays has their length embedded, but it is not the case for C++ pointers. You may need to add another parameter to `verifySignedRandom()` to explicitly specify the length of `originalRandom`.

Comment: And `strlen` can't be right either. The `strlen` function is only for C-style strings, not binary data.